# AはBにある versus BにAがある

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

- **お酒は**机の上にあります。
- 机の上に**お酒が**あります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was asked お酒はどこにありますか？ I might respond like this:

> お酒**は**机の上にあります。

Here, お酒 is old information (so you use は) and 机の上 is new information.

If I was asked 机の上には何がありますか？ I might respond like this:

> 机の上に**は**、お酒があります。

Here, 机の上 is old information and お酒 is new information.

When you say:

> 机の上にお酒があります。

both 机の上 and お酒 are normally new information.

Comment: In both cases everything before and including the は may be omitted as redundant. You both already know the topic of conversation (the Sake and the shelf, respectively), so typically a native speaker would not repeat it (unless getting time to think or for emphasis/clarification).